# Wordpress query pages with certain template

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to query Wordpress pages that have certain template?
Here's what I got, but doesn't show anything:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'template-city.php' )); ?>
                <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Of course, there is page template file named `template-city.php`

Comment: Um, how would this work though? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are a lot of pages on website - continents, with cities childred, which further have accomodation children, or restoraunt children etc. Each of theese pages have their own page template - so I would like to display all cities with query. Hope this helps?

Comment: It sounds like you need to wp_list_pages(), http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: Yes, but what if want to use pages' thumbnail? I don't want to display only city names in a list, I would like to have access to all things in a page, like thumbnail for example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if `post_type` is left out WP will look for post, and you are looking for pages.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',//it is a Page right?
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                'value' => 'template-city.php', // template name as stored in the dB
            )
        )
    );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args)
?>
```

Comment: Just a point of reminder for people seeing this: yes, you do need to have `meta_key`'s value be an array within an array for this to work.

Comment: Incase this isn't working for you, make sure the `value` path is correct, specifically if your template file is in a folder. In my case the `value` needed to be `page-templates/template-name.php`

Comment: Can multiple template names be passed into the query?

Comment: @Shadoath yes you can: `'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_wp_page_template','value' => ['template-city.php', 'template-other.php'], 'compare' => 'IN'))` see the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) for more info

Comment: Just don't forget to add 'posts_per_page' => -1 , or you will get only 10 results